# Как возобновить поток cin после ctrl+z

Tags: c++

```
while(cin >> x){/*do something*/}
```

Вопрос, если для выхода из цикла нажать ctrl + z, то после этого ни одна команда cin не будет работать. Подскажите, как исправить?

Comment: да никак думаю) ctrl + z закрывает поток консоли.

Comment: как сказал комментатор выше, поток закрывается, но в остальных случаях помогает очистка буффера cin.clear() cin.ignore()